# Is it possible to transfer data directly between two android devices to other users in the same network?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have two android mobile devices, connected to the same wireless network, and that network hasnt external/internet access.

Without third party software, is it possible to transfer data through wifi without knowing the ip from each other and without creating an hotspot? Something like we do on Windows (if 2 pcs are on same network, they can share information directly without internet access)

Starting with the basics, I would like to develop an application, where android phones on same network appears on a list , and then a user choose on of them and writes something - and if the other user have the same app running, appears that on his phone (and then he can reply of course - basically, a chat.

I know this make no practical sense, but believe makes all the sense for what I need to do (it's not a chat of course). If anyone knows anything, please help me - i found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know relatively little about the ins and outs of transferring data with different network protocols. But I would assume you'll at least need the ip of the device you are trying to send to.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the NSD feature introduced in the 4.1 release. Sounds like this is exactly what you need. http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send data or messages from one phone to another using the network you will eventually need the IP address of the recipient phone. However, If you don't care about targeting specific phones you could always send UDP broadcast packets that each device on the network should receive.

If you don't want to manually specify an IP you'll need to create a discovery protocol that a phone uses to discover all the other phones on the network. You could do this buy scanning all available IP addresses and checking to see if they are a valid android phone. Or you could have each phone broadcast its presence on the network using a UDP broadcast packet sent to a predefined port.

Once you have discovered all the phones on the network its really up to you to decide how you want to send the data between phones and there are hundreds of examples of how to send data between devices/computers/processes using sockets.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. However for your first suggestion, if I scan all the network, how can I see if it's a valid android phone? For your second suggestion, broadcasting to a specific port all the time, will not consume much energy?

Comment: If you wanted to scan the network. You'd need to create some sort of discovery protocol, which is probably more work than its worth.  To send out a single UDP packet every second or so would not consume much energy. We're talking about a few bytes here which is a drop in the bucket compared to how much data you device sends/receives just to maintain an active network connection.

Comment: So, with the second option, how can I verify if it's a valid android phone ?

Comment: You really can't. All you can do is verify that the packets you are receiving look they way you want them to look. Ideally you would define before hand what you want the broadcast packets to look like. You could put a predefined 64bit word in there, and maybe any other meta data you might care about. Then any device that receives those packets can assume they came from a valid device.  Keep in mind that anyone/device can send you packets that look valid.

Comment: Theorically, I understand now. Thanks for that. At application level, can you please point me to some information to how to broadcast to a specific port and how to build a specific packet? Many thanks.