# How to upload sqlite3 db file to server in Android?

Tags: android, upload, sqlite

I have a database in a Android app, which requires to upload it's database to a PC server.New to this area,where should I start?Other guys are uploading mp3,image,vedio and so on.I think there are  differences between those transactions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is a file.  You can query the OS for the database filename that you're using and push it anywhere you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have found a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340453/is-it-possible-to-transfer-data-directly-between-two-android-devices-to-other-us.But I'm still in the mist.